# ASP.NET Web API: One long method, how to ensure it'll be called once

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I have a long running request to a web service which should be cached on the server side after completion. My problem is - I don't know how to prevent it being called concurrently/simultaneously before it's cached after first request.

My thought is I should create a data request `Task` and store it in a concurrent dictionary. So every other request should check if `Task` is already running and wait for it to complete.

I've ended up with this:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task> tasksCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>();

public static T GetFromCache<T>(this ICacheManager<object> cacheManager, string name, Func<T> func)
{
    if (cacheManager.Exists(name))
        return (T)cacheManager[name];

    if (tasksCache.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        tasksCache[name].Wait();
        return (tasksCache[name] as Task<T>).Result;
    }

    var runningTask = Task.Run(() => func.Invoke());
    tasksCache[name] = runningTask;
    runningTask.Wait();

    var data = runningTask.Result;
    cacheManager.Put(name, data);
    tasksCache.TryRemove(name, out Task t);

    return data;
}
```

But this looks messy. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can put a synch variable server side. If the cache is not ready you just return with empty data. If that could be a valid scenario for you.

Comment: Nope, I need to serve response for each request.

Comment: Somewhat related: [ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117652/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider wrapping these in a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) for each task, which has built-in semantics for controlling concurrent initialization.

[This example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) demonstrates the use of the `Lazy<T>` class to provide lazy initialization with access from multiple threads.

You'll want to specify an appropriate [`LazyThreadSafetyMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Fully thread safe; uses locking to ensure that only one thread initializes the value. `ExecutionAndPublication`

Comment: IT'S ALIVE! :D Thx