# How to pass an async function to ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await, concurrentdictionary

This is a question related with both caching and asynchronous functions. In order to provide some context for my question, I'll explain a bit why I'm facing this problem with caching and async functions.

These days I'm refactoring an old piece of code meant to provide some user information given the user id. To fix the idea, imagine a signature like this:

```
public interface IUserInfoRetriever 
{
  UserInfo GetUserInfo(Guid userId);
}

public class UserInfoRetriever : IUserInfoRetriever 
{
   // implementation is discussed below
}
```

The class `UserInfoRetriever` has an instance of `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, UserInfo>` which is used as a cache (where the user id is the key).

This in-memory cache is pre filled the first time that the method `GetUserInfo` is called. The current way employed to do so requires to take a lock each time `GetUserInfo` is called, in order to check whether the cache initialization has already been done.

After the lock has been released the method [GetOrAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_GetOrAdd__0_System_Func__0__1__) of the ConcurrentDictionary is called in order to get the requested user info. The second parameter passed to GetOrAdd (the value factory used in the case of a cache miss) is a lambda expression which calls a remote web service able to provide user information. This call is currently done in a **blocking fashion** (using `Task<T>.Result`) because **ConcurrentDictionary does not support async calls**.

Here is some metacode to better understand the scenario:

```
public class UserInfoRetriever : IUserInfoRetriever 
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, UserInfo> userCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, UserInfo>();
    private bool isCacheInitialized = false;
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public UserInfo GetUserInfo(Guid userId) 
    {
        this.InitializeCache();

        return this.cache.GetOrAdd(userId, () => this.GetUserFromWebService(userId));
    }

    private void InitializeCache()
    {
        lock(this.locker)
        {
            if (this.isCacheInitialized)
            {
                return;
            }

            // read all the users available in the Users table of a database
            // put each user in the cache by using ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, UserInfo>.TryAdd()

            this.isCacheInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    private UserInfo GetUserFromWebService(Guid userId) 
    {
        // performs a call to a web service in a blocking fashion instead of using async methods of HttpClient class
        // this is due to the signature of ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>.GetOrAdd not supporting async functions as the second parameter
    }
}
```

This is clearly a mess. This class is doing too much and the method `InitializeCache` can be replaced by using the framework class `Lazy<T>` in order to get rid of both the lock and the flag `isCacheInitialized`.

Now it's time to close the introductory part and pass to the real question. **The hard bit in this scenario is the ConcurrentDictionary and its lack of support for async functions in the method GetOrAdd**. This is the whole point of my question.

Based on my knowledge there are four possible approaches:

- rely on a blocking call, as the current implementation is doing. I don't like the idea of doing an http call in a blocking fashion. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the callback provided to ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd is called only once. My web service call is a GET so it is idempotent, but this is less than ideal in my view.
- use `Task<UserInfo>` instead of `UserInfo` as the dictionary value. This trick is useful to workaround the lack of support for async functions. This however doesn't solve the issues with multiple executions of the callback function (this is due to the way ConcurrentDictionary is implemented)
- use the [asp.net core memory cache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/) instead of ConcurrentDictionary. This has the advantage that async functions are fully supported by the method [GetOrCreateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_CacheExtensions_GetOrCreateAsync__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_IMemoryCache_System_Object_System_Func_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_ICacheEntry_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___). Unfortunately there is no guarantee that the callback is called only once (see [here](https://blog.novanet.no/asp-net-core-memory-cache-is-get-or-create-thread-safe/) for more information).
- use the nuget package for [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache) that fixes both of the issues because it has a support for async function in the GetOrAdd cache method and it provides the guarantee that the async callback is called once. I don't know if there is a way to cache an item forever, but i could employ a very long absolute expiration in order to simulate a ConcurrentDictionary where the items never expire.

What approach do you suggest for the ConcurrentDictionary ? Are there other ways other than the ones I listed above to work with the ConcurrentDictionary when the factory method used to provide a missing item is async ?

**My question is only related to the problem of managing the lack of support for async functions of ConcurrentDictionary**. I'm looking for suggestion about that because there are several possible approaches to solve it. I explained the whole refactoring scenario at the sole purpose of being clearer and provide some context for my question.

**UPDATE 24th JULY 2019**

For the ones interested, here is my final implementation:

```
public sealed class InMemoryUserCache : IUserCache, IDisposable
  {
    private readonly IBackEndUsersRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>>> _cache;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _initializeCacheLocker;

    public InMemoryUserCache(IBackEndUsersRepository userRepository)
    {
      _userRepository = userRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepository));
      _cache = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>>>(
        InitializeCache,
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);
      _initializeCacheLocker = new SemaphoreSlim(2); // allows concurrency, but limit to 2 the number of threads that can concurrently initialize the lazy instance
    }

    public Task<BackEndUserInfo> GetOrAdd(
      Guid userId,
      Func<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>> userInfoFactory)
    {
      if (userInfoFactory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userInfoFactory));

      return _cache.Value.GetOrAdd(userId, ToSafeUserInfoFactory(userInfoFactory));
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>> InitializeCache()
    {
      _initializeCacheLocker.Wait();

      try
      {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>>();

        foreach (var user in _userRepository.FindAll())
        {
          cache[user.Id] = Task.FromResult(user);
        }

        return cache;
      }
      finally
      {
        _initializeCacheLocker.Release();
      }
    }

    private Func<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>> ToSafeUserInfoFactory(
      Func<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>> userInfoFactory) =>
        userId => TryExecuteUserInfoFactory(userInfoFactory, userId);

    private async Task<BackEndUserInfo> TryExecuteUserInfoFactory(
      Func<Guid, Task<BackEndUserInfo>> userInfoFactory,
      Guid userId)
    {
      try
      {
        return await userInfoFactory(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        _ = _cache.Value.TryRemove(userId, out var _);
        throw;
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      _initializeCacheLocker?.Dispose();
    }
  }
```

Comment: my first question would be ... why do you need all users in the cache? Are you even looking at the right thing

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu the cache initialization puts all the users available in the local database in the cache. They are not all the system users, but instead all the users that have already performed at least one action in the past. Consider that I do not know the historical decisions made by previous team members (I joined the project years later)

Comment: `Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the callback provided to ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd is called only once.` The standard solution to this is to `GetOrAdd` a `Lazy`. You can do the same with `MemoryCache`.

Comment: @mjwills I read a few article about using `Lazy<T>` as the dictionary value so that you are sure the callback is called only once. The main issue with lazy is that by default it caches exceptions. The guys of the LazyCache library also fixed this issue, they guarantee that exceptions are never saved in the cache

Comment: @EnricoMassone Read my below link about `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching`.

Comment: This might provide some useful information [ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117652/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-async)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bad idea to support async callbacks in `GetOrAdd`.  Obviously, the callback is doing a non-trivial amount of work or state change, or you'd have used the version where you prepare the new item ahead of time... but still, this is a synchronized access to a concurrent collection we're talking about.

What should happen if the same element of the ConcurrentDictionary is accessed before the callback completes?  With threading, you could have at most one operation in progress on the ConcurrentDictionary per thread, unless you did something really crazy with re-entrancy.  With Tasks and continuation-passing-style, you could end up with unbounded overlapping Dictionary requests, even unbounded recursion, without even trying.

Consider what should happen if a second cache lookup for the same user is made before the first one completes.  In your case, both lookups should probably return the data from the one network request.  To make that happen, change your `ConcurrentDictionary<UserId, User>` to a `ConcurrentDictionary<UserId, Task<User>>` and go ahead and pass your `async` function as the callback.  Its `Task` will get registered within the `Dictionary` when the async code blocks, instead of when it completes.... and this allows subsequent lookups to `await` the same already-in-flight `Task`.  This is your second bullet, but I'm not sure why you reached the conclusion that it handles multiple lookups badly.  It won't 100% prevent a duplicate lookup from resulting in independent network requests, but the race window is much smaller than it is for your current implementation.

Library behaviors should be designed in order to make correct operations easy, and straightforward operation correct (sometimes called "The Pit of Success").  `GetOrAddAsync` would make reasoning about the logic considerably more complex, which flies in the face of providing a general-purpose prebuilt thread-safe collection class.

If you have requirements for long-running element initialization on your shared collection, the general-purpose one isn't a good choice, and you'll want to build a thread-safe collection that is optimized for your particular use case.