# Different HTTP calls, await same Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

I have a `Task` which starts a win process, which generates file if its not created yet and returns it. The problem is that the action is called more than once. To be more precisely its `src` attribute of a `<track>` element.
I have `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task<string>>`
which keeps track of for which Id a process is currently running

```
public async Task<string> GenerateVTTFile(Guid Id)
{
  if (_currentGenerators.TryGetValue(id, out Task<string> task))
  {
     return await task; // problem is here?
  }

  var t = Run(); // Task
  _currentGenerators.TryAdd(id, t);

  return await t;
}
```

In the action method of the controller

```
var path = await _svc.GetSomePath();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
    var path = await svc.GenerateVTTFile(id);

    return PhysicalFile(path, "text/vtt");
} 

return PhysicalFile(path, "text/vtt");
```

`Run()` method is just starting `Process` and waits it.

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

What I want to achieve is to return the result of the same task for the same Id. It seems that if the `Id` already exists in the dictionary and I `await` it starts another process (calls Run method again).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you post the complete function / method? It _should_ work if you omitted the `await`s. But that would mean your Method returns a Task<string> to be awaited outside this call.

Comment: @Fildor I did change, but I don't think it will help much. If I set breakpoint I can see the `Run` method started twice for 2 http calls with same `Id` query parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the method atomic to protect the "dangerzone":

```
private SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public Task<string> GenerateVTTFile(Guid Id)
{
  _sem.Wait();
  try
  {
     if (_currentGenerators.TryGetValue(Id, out Task<string> task))
     {
        return task;
     }

     var t = Run(); // Task
     _currentGenerators.TryAdd(Id, t); // While Thread 1 is here,
                                       // Thread 2 can already be past the check above ...
                                       // unless we make the method atomic like here.

     return t;
   }
   finally
   {
      _sem.Release();
   }
}
```

Drawback here is, that also calls with *different* ids have to wait. So that makes for a bottleneck. Of course, you could make an effort but hey: the dotnet guys did it for you:

*Preferably*, you can use [GetOrAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.8) to do the same with only ConcurrentDictionary's methods:

```
public Task<string> GenerateVTTFile(Guid Id)
{
     // EDIT: This overload vv is actually NOT atomic!
     // DO NOT USE: 
     //return _currentGenerators.GetOrAdd(Id, () => Run());
     // Instead:
     return _currentGenerators.GetOrAdd(Id, 
                                        _ => new Lazy<Task<string>>(() => Run(id))).Value;
     // Fix "stolen" from Theodore Zoulias' Answer. Link to his answer below.
     // If you find this helped you, please upvote HIS answer.
}
```

Yes, it's *really* a "one-liner". 
Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61372518/982149 from which I took the fix for my flawed answer.

Comment: Thanks, works as a charm. One question only. What if a request with different `Id` as query parameter comes? If I understand correctly it will wait if there is already `thread` running for some other `Id`?

Comment: @Expressingx Unfortunately, yes. That's why it's probably better to use ConcurrentDictionary's own `GetOrAdd` (see my edited answer).

Comment: Definitely the one-liner is the go-to for my case. Just tested it and it behaves the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Expressingx I just read the "Remarks" on "GetOrAdd": It is actually also _not atomic_ when using the factory overload ... so, you may want to test this thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367407/11178549) already by João Reis, using simply the [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd) method is not enough to ensure that a `Task` will be created only once per key. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_GetOrAdd__1__0_System_Func__0___0__1____0_):

> If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads, `valueFactory` may be called multiple times, but only one key/value pair will be added to the dictionary.

The quick and lazy way to deal with this problem is to use the [`Lazy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class. Instead of storing `Task` objects in the dictionary, you could store `Lazy<Task>` wrappers. This way even if a wrapper is created multiple times per key, all extraneous wrappers will be discarded without their [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.value) property requested, and so without duplicate tasks created.

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, <Lazy<Task<string>>> _currentGenerators;

public Task<string> GenerateVTTFileAsync(Guid id)
{
    return _currentGenerators.GetOrAdd(id,
        _ => new Lazy<Task<string>>(() => Run(id))).Value;
}
```

Comment: Andrew Lock goes into detail on this approach in his [blog post](https://andrewlock.net/making-getoradd-on-concurrentdictionary-thread-safe-using-lazy) from a few years ago.

Comment: If the valueFactory is not expensive (Lazy.Value blocks the threads) then using Lazy is a much better approach than the one described by my answer simply because it is so much simpler, +1

Comment: In retrospect I am no longer feeling comfortable with the `Lazy<Task<T>>` combination. It is a dangerous mix of a blocking and an asynchronous component, that may cause threads to be blocked and loss of scalability in some scenarios. Currently I am in favor of implementing the same functionality using nested tasks (`Task<Task>`), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117652/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-async/65694270#65694270 "ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd async").

Answer (score 2):

In order to have multiple concurrent calls of that method but only one for each id, you need to use `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` with `SemaphoreSlim`.

`GetOrAdd` is not enough because the factory parameter might be executed more than once, see "Remarks" here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.8

Here is an example:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Generator> _currentGenerators = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Generator>();

public async Task<string> GenerateVTTFile(Guid id)
{
    var generator = _currentGenerators.GetOrAdd(id, _ => new Generator());

    return await generator.RunGenerator().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public class Generator
{
    private int _started = 0;

    private Task<string> _task;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    public async Task<string> RunGenerator()
    {
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            await Initialize().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return await Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _task, null, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            // check again after acquiring the lock
            if (IsInitialized())
            {
                return;
            }

            var task = Run();
            _ = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _task, task);
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _started, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _started, 0, 0) == 1;
    }

    private async Task<string> Run()
    {
        // your implementation here
    }
}
```