# How to create a C# Task without execute and with await inside, add into a dictionary and execute awaiting the result and then remove from dictionary

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I would like to create a `Task` that calls an async method with `await` keyword, then add into a control dictionary and after this run the task.
I was able to create the Task and start it using both, `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run` method, but doing this the task starts before I was able to add into a dictionary.

The next code shows 4 examples tasks. The `task1` shows what I need but without a async/await call inside of a task. The `task2` and the `task3` shows what I want to do with a task but starts the task before add into a dictionary. The `task4`, doesn't compile, but shows what I would like to get it:

```
public Task<int> Dummy()
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

Dictionary<string, Task> TaskController = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

public async Task LoadData()
{
    Task<int> task1 = new Task<int>(() => 0);
    TaskController.Add("a", task1);
    task1.Start();
    await task1;
    TaskController.Remove("a");

    Task<int> task2;
    task2 = await Task.Factory.StartNew<Task<int>>(async () => await Dummy());
    TaskController.Add("b", task2);
    //task2.Start();
    await task2;
    TaskController.Remove("b");

    Task<int> task3;
    task3 = Task.Run<int>(async () => await Dummy());
    TaskController.Add("b", task3);
    //task3.Start();
    await task3;
    TaskController.Remove("b");

    //I would like to to this
    Task<int> task4;
    task4 = new Task<int>(async => await Dummy());
    TaskController.Add("b", task4);
    task4.Start();
    await task4;
    TaskController.Remove("b");
}
```

Is there any way to do this or it was not possible?

NOTE:
I was trying with the `TaskExtensions.Unwrap` extension method but I suspect that it also runs the task before.

Comment: Are you trying to run the taks in parallel?

Comment: Are you trying to create a cache? If yes, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once) question interesting, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117652/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-async).

Comment: Thanks for specify the aswered question because I can't found it. At least I was not very lost when I tryped the Unwrap method, but I was trying to start the unwraped task insted the internal task before unwraped.